# List all network printers per user

Tags: c#, wmi, .net, printers

at my work, we install printers on the per user basis. I'm trying to write a backup program that would list all networked printers given a username. Is that at all possible ? via WMI or System.IO would be OK. Here is the code that lists all the machines networked printers but not per user.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ConnectionOptions objConnection = new ConnectionOptions();

        objConnection.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

        objConnection.EnablePrivileges = true;



         string backupselectedcomputer = "Some Computer Name"

          ManagementScope objScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + backupselectedcomputer     +"\\root\\cimv2",objConnection); 
         objScope.Connect();

         SelectQuery selectQuery = new SelectQuery();
         selectQuery.QueryString = "Select * from win32_Printer Where Local = FALSE";
         ManagementObjectSearcher MOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher(objScope, selectQuery);
         ManagementObjectCollection MOC = MOS.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in MOC)

        {

       //lbBackupprinters is a list box
            lbBackupprinters.Items.Add(mo["Name"].ToString().ToUpper());
         }

 }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: if it is assigned per user, you must have added the printer in active directory, try to find there...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468139/how-to-programmatically-search-a-printer-in-active-directory

Comment: we use a VBS script to add the printer to the computer on a per user basis from a print server, not from AD. It looks like i'm going to have to remotley parse through the registry and find the user SID then go through HKCU or HKUSERS and get it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a way. Here is the code for anyone that comes across this issue.

```
 private void ddlBackupselectuser_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lbBackupprinters.Items.Clear();

        string selecteduser = ddlBackupselectuser.Text;

        string computer = ddlBackupselectcomp.Text;

        string sid;

        lblBackuppwd.Visible = true;
        txtBackuppwd.Visible = true;
        cboBackuppwdshow.Visible = true;

        //BEGIN GRAB PRINTERS FROM REGISTRY

        try
        {
            NTAccount ntuser = new NTAccount(selecteduser);
            SecurityIdentifier sID = (SecurityIdentifier)ntuser.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            lblBackupStatus.Text = sID.ToString();
            sid = sID.ToString();
        }

        catch (IdentityNotMappedException)
            {
                lblBackupStatus.Text = "ERROR "+ ddlBackupselectuser.Text.ToString() + " contains no profile information";

                lbBackupprinters.Items.Add("No Printers Found");

            return;

            }



                 ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
                 co.EnablePrivileges = true;
                 co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

                 System.Net.IPHostEntry h = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName());
                 string IPAddress = h.AddressList.GetValue(0).ToString();
                 string lm = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName().ToString();

                try
                 {


                     ManagementScope myScope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + computer + "\\root\\default", co);
                     ManagementPath mypath = new ManagementPath("StdRegProv");
                     ManagementClass wmiRegistry = new ManagementClass(myScope, mypath, null);


                    const uint HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = unchecked((uint)0x80000002);
                     //ManagementClass wmiRegistry = new ManagementClass("root/default",
                     //"StdRegProv",null);

                     string keyPath = @"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Providers\\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\\" + sid + "\\Printers\\Connections";
                     object[] methodArgs = new object[] { HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, keyPath, null };
                     uint returnValue = (uint)wmiRegistry.InvokeMethod("EnumKey", methodArgs);


                     if (null != methodArgs[2])
                     {
                         string[] subKeys = methodArgs[2] as String[];

                         if (subKeys == null)
                         {
                             lbBackupprinters.Items.Add("No Printers Found");
                             return;
                         }

                         ManagementBaseObject inParam = wmiRegistry.GetMethodParameters("GetStringValue");
                         inParam["hDefKey"] = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;


                         string keyName = "";


                         foreach (string subKey in subKeys)
                         {
                             //Display application name
                             keyPath = @"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Print\\Providers\\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\\" + sid + "\\Printers\\Connections" + subKey;
                             keyName = "DisplayName";
                             inParam["sSubKeyName"] = keyPath;
                             inParam["sValueName"] = keyName;
                             ManagementBaseObject outParam = wmiRegistry.InvokeMethod("GetStringValue", inParam, null);



                                 lbBackupprinters.Items.Add(subKey);


                         }
                     }

                     else
                     {

                         lbBackupprinters.Items.Add("No Printers Found");                             

                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
```

Comment: Wow, this works!  It gives me access to the printer list even from a serivce!