# C# - Get Printer ACL for Active Directory published printers

Tags: c#, printing, active-directory, acl

Enumerating printers in C# that are published to Active Directory is fairly simple and works without problems.

My actual problem is, that I want to limit the number of returned printers to the ones I (or, respectively, the user) is having access to based on the printer queue ACL.

As already mentioned here [How to programmatically search a printer in Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468139/how-to-programmatically-search-a-printer-in-active-directory) the actual ACL of the Queue (if i'm allowed to print/manage etc.) is not stored in the Active Directory object itself.

A second loop calling to all the actual printer Queues would be ok too but yet i have not found how to get to a remote printer queue ACL either.

Any ideas on how to call the printer object/extract the ACL once I have all AD-published printers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use WMI. There are two classes I'd look at:

1. `Win32_Printer` has a `GetSecurityDescriptor()` method.
2. `Win32_Share` has a `GetAccessMask()` method.

I'm not sure offhand which one is the right option but between the two I expect you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, number 1 was exactly what I was looking for! I guess it is the best way that can be achieved without having the DACL accessible via an AD query. But it does the trick